# Idea for globally unique record-holding trophy badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

As the title says, how about making available "trophy" style badges, that are globally unique (only one such badge exists per site), and is bestowed to the current holder of some sort of record. Records, of course, can be broken, so the badge is not permanent and is transferrable.

It would be nice if a "shadow" of the trophy still remains after a user lost it, even if just for the memories =) Would be even nicer if each trophy has a dedicated historical trail page that other people can follow.

Some obvious overall records are:

- Highest rep points
- Most rep gain in a day
- Most rep lost in a day
- Highest average points per day
- Quickest to [Mortarboard], [Epic], [Legendary]
- Quickest to [Enthusiast], [Fanatic]
- Most [Enlightened], etc
- Most successful bounty hunter
- Most [Tumbleweed] (sad!)

You can also have daily records that are reset every day:

- Most rep gain yesterday
- Most acceptance yesterday

You can also have week/month counterparts too, of course.

Note that the "Quickest to" records are not defensible. A user can only set that record once in his lifetime, and if lost afterward, can never won it ever again. Some users will never be able to win it ever, period.

Comment: I posted the same idea a while back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/please-add-trophies-that-get-awarded-to-the-user-who-has-performed-best-based-o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nah, Jon Skeet would have all of them.

Comment: @Downvoter Except the TumbleWeed one.

Comment: Blasphemy. He would find a way to have them all, even "Most [Tumbleweed]"

Answer (score 3):

They already have this for tags.  Click on any tag and then click the stats tab near the top, and you can see the top users for that tag for all time and for the last 30 days.

Comment: Ah, that is pretty nice!!! I should've been more adventurous in exploring the site's UI, but there's just so many things that I lost track of them.

Comment: @poly - and yet you want to introduce more things to lose track of!  ;-D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Tumbleweed is one of those badges that is awarded more than once, and it's too easy to get.  Just post some valid but really difficult question about an obscure subject.